# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape and write output in the same line for each iteration using the following code.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.siema.org/members.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
tds = soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class':'content'})
for table in zip(*[iter(tds)]*2):
    data = [re.sub('\s+', ' ', text).strip().encode('utf8') for text in table.find_all(text=True) if text.strip()]
    print [','.join(data) for x in data]
```

right now I am getting output like

```
A K Ponnusamy & Co
cjm@yahoo.co.in
Manufacturing of Rough Castings
Aelenke PL Industrials

All types of Pulleys
Agri Pump Industries

Submersible Pumpsset Jet Pumps Centrifugal Monoblocks Motor & pumps
Akshaya Engineering

pumpsets
Altech Industries
altech@vsnl.com|www.altechindustries.org
Engineering College Lab Equipment (FM and Therai lab Equipment)
Ammurun Foundry
ammarun@vsnl.com|www.ammarun.com
Grey Iron & S.G. Iron Rough Castings
Anugraha Valve Castings Ltd
anugraha@anugrahavalvecastings.com
valve & spares
Apex Bright Bars (Cbe) Pvt Ltd
apexcbe@sify.com
```

I wanted it to be like

```
A K Ponnusamy & Co  |cjm@yahoo.co.in  |  Manufacturing of Rough Castings
Aelenke PL Industrials |    | All types of Pulleys
```

Comment: What is `zip(*[iter(tds)]*2)` supposed to be doing?

Comment: `[','.join(data) for x in data]` Does not do what you are expecting it to: `[",".join(x) for x in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']] == ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`. To join the items together into a single comma-separated string, do `",".join(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']) == "a,b,c,d"`

Comment: Previsouly I was using `','.join(data)` only. It was still writing in separate line.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I thought it would help me writing in single line for each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very similar to previous answer but with slightly more desired output.

```
for table in zip( *[iter(tds)]*3 ):
    row = [', '.join([re.sub('\s+', ' ', text).strip().encode('utf8') 
                        for text in td.find_all(text=True) 
                        if text.strip()])
                       for td in table]
    print ' | '.join(row)
```

Which gives the following ouyput:

```
Name & Address of the Company | E Mail & Web | Product Manufactured
A K Ponnusamy & Co | cjm@yahoo.co.in | Manufacturing of Rough Castings
Aelenke PL Industrials |  | All types of Pulleys
...
```

Answer (score 4):

your `zip(*[iter(tds)]*2` is returning a list of tuples containing td tags. The table variable is therefore a tuple which is does not have the find_all method.

This:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.siema.org/members.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
tds = soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class':'content'})
for table in zip( *[iter(tds)]*3 ):
    data = []
    for td in table:
        data += [re.sub('\s+', ' ', text).strip().encode('utf8') for text in td.find_all(text=True) if text.strip()]
    print ', '.join(data)
```

Returns:

```
Name & Address of the Company, E Mail & Web, Product Manufactured
A K Ponnusamy & Co, cjm@yahoo.co.in, Manufacturing of Rough Castings
Aelenke PL Industrials, All types of Pulleys
Agri Pump Industries, Submersible Pumpsset, Jet Pumps, Centrifugal Monoblocks, Motor & pumps
... more skipped ...
```

The first TD tags on that page include the headers, though, you may want to skip those.

Comment: It is returning in one single line, which I do not want. If want each set of data from each iteration to be in a line. not the whole output. Hope I am clear

Comment: It is **not** returning two identical td tags. It is pairing up td tags, two at a time.

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing that out, it makes more sense now.

Comment: Now for the same thing, how do I loop the url from a to z in http://www.siema.org/bpage.html ? like we use to do for numbers using `xrange`?